# Gaussian Mixture for detecting outliers

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, outliers, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm trying to make a simple outlier detection program that is able to correctly, or almost correctly, identify values in a data set that could be potential outliers because they don't fall in the distribution of the rest of the values in the same data set.

1. I can't use supervised techniques like classification or regression because I am not granted any historical, labeled data to train a model with, so I will be using unsupervised techniques, like clustering.
2. I was going to use k-means clustering, but I read multiple articles saying that k-means works horribly with outliers, and some of them recommended me to try a gaussian mixture model.

I know Gaussian Mixture Models work by creating different clusters that represent different distributions. I am using Spark's (Apache) version of Gaussian Mixture Model and this gives me two columns relevant to my problem: a **prediction** column that gives me the cluster for which a data point in the data set has been assigned to, and a **probability** column, which is a column that gives me the probabilities that each value has to be assigned to each one of the clusters. Working with this approach, how can I determine outliers?

I thought of labeling as outliers those values which are on the lower cluster (cluster with the smallest number of points) but this is not a good approach because on the scenario that there are no outliers, there will always be one cluster smaller than the rest since GMM doesn't evenly distributes the values in the clusters. Any alternative approach I could use?

Comment: This review may be of interest: Chandola et al. (2007). Anomaly Detection: A Survey.

Comment: Why not to use the probabilities? Lower probability on all clusters will mean an outlier, with some reasonable definition for lower.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard outlier detection methods: kNN outlier, LOF, Loop?

Comment: Clustering is hard. And most algorithms are quite sensitive to outliers. So I'd rather first remove outliers, then cluster.

Comment: @DataD'oh In Spark's implementation of GMM, the model creates two clusters, and what I've noticed is that usually the outliers will be grouped in one cluster and the "normal" data will be gathered in the other cluster. However, I can't think of a way to know when one of those two clusters will contain anomalous data or not. Also, since there are only two clusters, each value will have a high probability for one cluster and lower for the other one, and I can't really get outliers from this

Comment: @Anony-Mousse the idea is not really to do clustering but detect or alert about possible outliers using a machine learning approach. Since I am not given any labeled, historical data, the only solution left is to do unsupervised training, and clustering was the approach I thought would be more viable. I don't want to follow a statistical approach because that way is very biased and dependent on the distribution of the data, and machine learning tends to work better.

Comment: The methods I listed are all unsupervised and non-parametric. Why do you think they won't work for you? Why don't you just *try* these well established methods?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Because I've already tried them. I tried using both the IQR method and the standard deviation method and they are very limited to the distribution of the data. If the data is very spread, I have to put a tighter threshold to be able to detect the outliers. If the data is not very spread, I have to put a less tight threshold, otherwise normal data will be branded as an outlier. EDIT: I'm talking about the statistical approach based purely on stats and not on machine learning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63455/discussion-between-guillermo-herrera-and-anony-mousse).

Comment: What about the unsupervised outlier detection methods I listed, that come from data mining and not statistics?

Comment: Any luck with the anomaly detection using GMM?

Comment: Notice that k-means is a special case (simplified version of) of GMM

Answer (score 2):

There is a smart way to do this that is implemented by JMP software.  In the GMM fitting, there is an option for "outlier cluster" that can be checked.  The description of this is below:

> The outlier cluster option assumes a uniform distribution and is less
>   sensitive to outliers than the standard Normal Mixtures method. This
>   fits a cluster to catch outliers that do not fall into any of the
>   normal clusters. The distribution of observations that fall in the outlier
>   cluster is assumed to be uniform over the hypercube that encompasses
>   the observations.

So what does this mean?  Well, it's just an additional latent factor (distribution) with a prior (same as the other mixture components) that is updated during the expectation step.  Naturally the data points that don't fall near a legitimate Gaussian cluster end up with a higher probability of being part of the [sparse] uniform distribution.

It works well and is something akin to finding outliers via DBSCAN clustering except with less tuning and investigation up front to set hyperparameters....but frankly it's not really that much more magical than just fitting a GMM without it and taking something like the lowest 0.5% quantile of points or similar (the quantile % then becomes a hyperparameter).  The only difference here is that the output of the algorithm chooses them as a result of the fitting.  Note however the group membership results will change with the number of latent units (which is a hyperparameter in the case of a GMM), so you either pay Peter or Paul...there's nothing out there that will tell you what an outlier is without making some kind of assumption or setting a hyper-parameter up front.

Comment: That sounds like a great option. Is anyone aware of an implementation in Python?

Comment: Seem like Pomegranate library using a GeneralMixture with Uniform and Gaussian can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, not using Gaussian processes:

If your dataset is not too big, you could use *hierarchical clustering* with a linkage method that creates unbalanced trees. The thinner branches of the tree would then represent the outliers.

I happen to know that the `single` linkage method of R's `hclust()` function   method tends to produce unblanced trees. You would call it as `hclust(dist(mydata), method = "single")`

Comment: I've tried hierarchical clustering, Bisecting K-Means, and that approach didn't work well. Again, as I mentioned, very few clustering methods work for detecting outliers. Most of them don't work when working with outliers.