# Using Gaussian Mixture Model for outlier detection

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Can someone summarize how to use Gaussian Mixture Model for outlier detection purpose. I am more interested in a general method and not so much the mathematical aspects of GMM's

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/236363/201327